# How to use preg_replace to give quote in number character?

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I have string like this:

```
$str="123 1231 41241 124124";
```

How to convert those string into this output in PHP?

```
$output="'123','1231','41241','124124'";
```

Comment: If you just need to replace spaces by ',' and then surround your string with 's str_replace will do.

Comment: Why require the use of preg_replace ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't need `preg_replace`. `str_replace` is fine:

```
<?php 
$str="123 1231 41241 124124";
$output = "'".str_replace(" ", "','", $str)."'";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like:

```
<?php 
$str="123 1231 41241 124124";
//This
$output = "'".implode("','",explode(' ',$str))."'";//'123','1231','41241','124124'
//Or
$output = "'".str_replace(' ',"','",$str)."'"; //'123','1231','41241','124124'
?>
```

Pretty sure there's also many other way todo it that doesn't involve regex.